# phpexcel there is a callback function or something else to give a feedback during file load operations?

Tags: callback, load, phpexcel

there is a way to get some sort of feedback during file load?

as example if i use below code with a file with 50.000 row and 26 columns:

```
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("big_file_test.xlsx");
```

the application will "freeze" for about 3 minutes before continue and i'm not able to give some real feedback to users (only some sort of fake loader animation).

so, there is a way to get something like a row or, better, row / column counter during file loading?

thank you

Comment: Simple answer, "No there isn't".

Comment: Best answer I can suggest is not to handle large files ina  user web request, but to use back-end processing (send the request to a queue or similar). Then you can respond immediately to the user with a "your file is now being processed" messages

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But my primary objective is to find a way to give a feedback and i think that your suggestion not change in any way my situation. Finally I'm not able to give a real feedback.. there no difference between waiting for 5 minute on a page that load the file server side or waiting for a process that work in a queue. From the user point of view, if the file need 5 minute to be completely analyzed I'm not able to tell it to my users. The only difference is that i can schedule work load but not more i think.

Comment: In that case, the only way to provide feedback will be to edit the PHPExcel code to do so yourself

Comment: do you have any idea where i can start? just a quick hint to start more quickly :D thank you!

Comment: Not easily, no.... you'd need to do something in the appropriate Reader, in this case the Excel2007 Reader; but as it loads by cell rather than by row, it isn't a simple piece of coding